# Do torsion-free $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules on curves have dimension one?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, coherent-sheaves, projective-schemes

Let $X$ be a curve (scheme of dimension 1, say noetherian, projective, Cohen-Macaulay all of whose irreducible components have dimension 1) and let $\mathcal{F}$ be a coherent, torsion-free $\mathcal{O}_X$-module (i.e. locally on open subsets $U \subseteq X$ we know that only zero-divisors of $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ can kill elements of $\mathcal{F}$).

> Does $\mathcal{F}$ have dimension 1?

On affine schemes $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ this is true:

Then $\mathcal{F}$ is given by some $A$-module $M$ and we have
$$\dim M = \dim \operatorname{Supp}(M) = \dim V(\operatorname{Ann}(M)).$$
Now that $M$ is torsion-free, the annihilator of $M$ is contained in the set of zero-divisors of $A$, which is $\bigcup_{P \in \operatorname{Spec}(A),\,P \text{ minimal}} P$.

By prime avoidance we obtain that $\operatorname{Ann}(M) \subseteq P$ for $P$ minimal prime. And hence 
$$V(P) \subseteq V(\operatorname{Ann}(M))$$
which now provides $\dim V(\operatorname{Ann}(M)) = 1$ since the same is true for the irreducible component $V(P)$  of $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$, by assumption.

But I don't know how to go to the global case.

Comment: How about covering $X$ by affines $U_i$, so that $\operatorname{supp}(\mathcal{F})=\bigcup \operatorname{supp}(\mathcal{F})\cap U_i=\bigcup \operatorname{supp}(\mathcal{F}|_{U_i})$ is an open covering. Now the dimension of $\operatorname{supp}(\mathcal{F})$ is the supremum of the dimensions of $\operatorname{supp}(\mathcal{F}|_{U_i})$ which you know to be $1$.

Comment: @user363120 This would work if all the $U_i$ are again equidimensional (having irreducible components which are all of dimension 1).